# Javascript insert content in a string at different positions / lengths

Tags: javascript

I have a string and I have multiple `offset` and `length` values. For example:

```
var str = '0123456789';

var matches = [{
    offset: 2,
    length: 3
}, {
    offset: 6,
    length: 2
}];
```

The goal is to insert a `<span>` **before** the offset and a `</span>` **after** the offset + length. In the above example, the string would look like that (spaces were added for readability) :

```
str = '01 <span class="red"> 234 </span> 5 <span class="red"> 67 </span> 89';
```

**What I have tried**:

```
function splitValue(value, offset, length) {

    return value.substring(0, offset) + ' <span class="red"> ' + value.substring(offset, offset + length) + ' </span> ' + value.substring(offset + length, value.length);
}

matches.forEach(function (match) {

    console.log(splitValue(str, match.offset, match.length));
});
```

**Output**:

```
01 <span class="red"> 234 </span> 56789
012345 <span class="red"> 67 </span> 89
```

This is good.

**Issue**:

I can't replace the string value with the function output in the forEach, because everything will be shifted after the first loop.

```
matches.forEach(function (match) {

    str = splitValue(str, match.offset, match.length);
});

console.log(str);
```

**Output**:

```
01 <sp <span class="red"> an </span>  class="red"> 234 </span> 56789
```

How can I achieve that?

I'd like to **avoid recalculating the next offsets** by adding the length of the inserted content (I know that would work). Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about just applying them in reverse order?

Comment: Sorting by offset and running from greatest to least may help, but you don't have any way to account for overlaps.

Comment: There will be no overlaps. Thanks for the 2 comments above. Sounds good :-)

Comment: @ChrisC If you want to put that as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you! Sometimes the easiest answers are the hardest to find ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get your current code working in a loop would be to loop backwards of the list of matches (assuming they are in the position order).

You could alternatively sort you matches backwards by offset and then loop through that.

Comment: Thought this is the accepted answer (and its mine) I do like Bogdan.Nourescu's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented a way to do this (it should work even if the values overlap):

And i've made a js fiddle to see [it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/3g2j1gg8/)

```
var str = '0123456789';

var matches = [{
    offset: 2,
    length: 3
}, {
    offset: 6,
    length: 2
}];
var insertionPoints = [];
for (var i in matches){
    insertionPoints.push({location:matches[i].offset,val:'<span class="red">'});
    insertionPoints.push({
        location: matches[i].offset+matches[i].length,
        val:'</span>'});
}
insertionPoints.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.location- a.location;
});
console.log(insertionPoints);
for(var i in insertionPoints){
    str=str.substring(0, insertionPoints[i].location)
    +insertionPoints[i].val
    +str.substring(insertionPoints[i].location);
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: It doesn't work with overlapping points but I won't have any in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var str = '0123456789';
var sections = [];

var matches = [{
    offset: 2,
    length: 3
}, {
    offset: 6,
    length: 2
}];

for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    var arr = str.split('');

    var match = matches[i];
    var section = arr.splice(match.offset, match.length).join('');

    sections.push(section);
}

for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    str = str.split(sections[i]).join('<span class="red">' + sections[i] + '</span>');
}

console.log(str);
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gf0kvy8e/